# SSIS truncation error only in control flow

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a package that giving me a very confusing "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page" error but only when I run the full package in the control flow, not when I run just the task by itself.

The first task takes CSV files and combines them into one file. The next task reads the output of the previous file and begins to process the records. What is really odd is the truncation error is thrown in the flat file source in the 2nd step. This is the exact same flat file source which was the destination in the previous step.

If there was a truncation error wouldn't that be thrown by the previous step that tried to create the file? Since the 1st step created the file without truncation, why can't I just read that same file in the very next task?

Note - Only thing that makes this package different from the others I have worked on is I am dealing with special characters and using code page 65001 UTF-8 to capture the fields that have special characters. My other packages were all referencing flat file connection managers with code page 1252.

[image: control flow showing both steps]

[image: data flow showing error with flat file source]

Comment: What sort of task is the first task?   is it a Data Flow Task?

Comment: problem is prob in your control flow then.  May you post screen shots?

Comment: The 1st task is a foreach loop that merges each CSV file. The 2nd task is a data flow task that at the very top uses the output file generated by the foreach loop as an input file. I will see if I can add a JPG file.

Comment: As a reminder, if I run just the 2nd task by itself there is no error thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the foreach loop and using the ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow expression where I have the formula "@[User::count_raw_input_rows] < 0". I have a variable initialized to -1 and I assign it to the ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow for the flat file. When in the loop I update the variable with a row counter on each read of a CSV file. This puts the header in the first time (-1) but then avoids repeating on all the other CSV files. When I exit the loop and try to read the input file it treats the header as data and blows up. I only avoided this on my last package because I didn't tighten the column definitions for the flat file like I did with this package. Thanks for the help.